# Filtering option values from datalist if I change from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know my post has been duplicated, but i failed finding post that appropriate me.

I have a code :

```html
<select project="myclass" class="form-control" name="myclass" id="myclass" onchange="" value="--">
  <option>--</option>
  <option>X TKJ 1</option>
  <option>X TKJ 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Student Name" list="checkName" autocomplete="off" required>
<datalist id="checkName">
  <option value="X TKJ 1">ALEX</option>
  <option value="X TKJ 2">JOHN</option>
  <option value="X TKJ 1">SAM</option>
  <option value="X TKJ 2">ANDY</option>
</datalist>
```

How to if I select `X TKJ 2` datalist will filter value by `X TKJ 2`. so if I input `ALEX`, it's not display in list besause from `X TKJ 1`, but if I select `--`, all name will displayed on datalist.

Comment: do you want display selected value right in input text??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('#myclass').on('change', function(){
 var opt = $(this).find('option:selected');
 $('#checkName option').prop('disabled', false);
 if(opt.length > 0 && opt.text() != '--') {
  $('#checkName option').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#checkName option[value="'+opt.text()+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select project="myclass" class="form-control" name="myclass" id="myclass" onchange="" value="--">
    <option>--</option>
    <option>X TKJ 1</option>
    <option>X TKJ 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Student Name" list="checkName" autocomplete="off" required>
<datalist id="checkName">
    <option value="X TKJ 1">ALEX</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 2">JOHN</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 1">SAM</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 2">ANDY</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code. But you have to know that:

1. It's bad to set the same value to 2 options.
2. It's better to keep a variable with the list of the options and filter from it.

But with your code, that's will work.

```js
var options = $('#checkName option').clone();

$('#myclass').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val(),
      filterOptions = val == '' ? options : options.filter('[value="' + val + '"]');
  $('#checkName').html('').append(filterOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select project="myclass" class="form-control" name="myclass" id="myclass" onchange="" value="--">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option>X TKJ 1</option>
    <option>X TKJ 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Student Name" list="checkName" autocomplete="off" required>
<datalist id="checkName">
    <option value="X TKJ 1">ALEX</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 2">JOHN</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 1">SAM</option>
    <option value="X TKJ 2">ANDY</option>
</datalist>
```